# SQL -- need help about table update

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table like:

[image]

I am trying update 'No Data' with 'NULL' in all columns. Is there any easy procedure to update? Thanks.

Comment: What is the column type? Is "No Data" a string? I think the GUI you are using just displays "NULL" as "No Data".

Comment: Yes 'No Data' is a string like others(i.e. neck, eye...). I want to make it blank (NULL).

Answer (score 1):

just repeat this for every column:

```
UPDATE table
SET Bleeding_event_1 = NULL
WHERE Bleeding_event_1 = 'No Data'
```

Yet another way to do it, more complex on code, but as it is dynamic it will adjust to any number of columns. You just run it once and it gets done for all the columns!

```
USE <dbname_where_table_is>
GO

DECLARE @column varchar(256)
DECLARE @sql varchar(512)

-- We'll use a cursor to cycle through each column name belonging to the table
DECLARE cursor_columns CURSOR FOR
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE TABLE_NAME = '<table_name>'  -- If you have more than one table with same name, add schema filter

OPEN cursor_columns
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_columns INTO @column

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    -- Again, may use <schema_name>.<table_name> instead of just <table_name>
    SET @sql = 'UPDATE <table_name> SET ' + @column + ' = NULL WHERE ' + @column + ' = ''No Data'''
    EXEC(@sql)
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_columns INTO @column
END

CLOSE cursor_columns
DEALLOCATE cursor_columns
```